# Copy data from one sheet, add current date to each new row, and paste

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've done some reading but my limited knowledge on scripts is making things difficult. I want to:

1. Copy a variable number of rows data range, known colums, from one sheet titled 'Download'
2. Paste that data in a new sheet titled 'Trade History' from Column B
3. In the new sheet, add today's date formatted (DD/MM/YYYY) in a new column A for each record copied

[The data in worksheet 'Download' uses IMPORTHTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE0Zy.png)

[The data copied from `Download` to store a historical record needs a `date` in Column A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TsV1.png)

I've managed to get 1 and 2 working, but can't work out the 3rd. See current script below.

```
function recordHistory() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Trade_History');
var source = sheet.getRange("a2:E2000");
  ss.getSheetByName('Download').getRange('A2:E5000').copyTo(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 2))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) to format today's date to DD/MM/YYYY.

Because you're copying one set of values, and then next to it (in column A), pasting another, I altered your code a bit as well.

```
function recordHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
      destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Trade_History');
  var sourceData = ss.getSheetByName('Download').getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<sourceData.length; i++) {
    var row = sourceData[i];
    var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT+10', 'dd/MM/yyyy'); // AEST is GMT+10
    row.unshift(today); // Places data at the beginning of the row array
  }
  destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow()+1, // Append to existing data
                            1, // Start at Column A
                            sourceData.length, // Number of new rows to be added (determined from source data)
                            sourceData[0].length // Number of new columns to be added (determined from source data)
                           ).setValues(sourceData); // Printe the values
}
```

Start by [getting the values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) of the source data. This returns an array that can be looped through to add today's date. Once the date has been added to all of the source data, determine the range boundaries for where it will be printed. Rather than simply selecting the start cell as could be done with the `copyTo()` method, the full dimensions now have to be defined. Finally, print the values to the defined range.